# Why some users are able to see pages which they shouldn't?

Tags: permissions

I have some pages and 2 groups with one user in each. Those pages aren't shared with those 2 groups and users in those groups, I also removed those Groups from permissions list in those pages' settings.

Hoewever, those users in those groups have Access to those pages. HOW?

**EDIT** They can't edit those pages, but they can view the content in it.

Comment: Are you sure those users do not have access to those pages through another groups such like site visitors, members or some else?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the permissions page for the page in question?

Comment: Are you using Claims based authentication? Is this SP2013 or 2010?

Comment: SP2013. Not sure what you mean with Claims based authentication. Explain if you can.

Answer (score 1):

**Check permissions for a user or group for a site**

1. Open the SharePoint site on which you want to check permissions.
2. On the Site Actions menu Site Actions menu, click Site Settings.
3. On the Site Settings page, under Users and Permissions, click Check
   Effective permissions.
4. On the Check Effective Permissions page, in the User/Group box, type the e-mail address of the user or distribution group for which you want to verify permissions, and then click the Check Names icon.
5. Click Check Now.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-sharepoint-services-help/check-permissions-for-a-user-or-group-HA010362860.aspx

There you can see the persmission the user have. Make sure that forbidden user are not in those groups.

Another things you can check:

1. Is the user in Site Collection Administrators?
2. Have you break the inheritance? (Stop Inheriting Permissions button in the Permission Tools tab Edit group) [example link](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/break-inheritance-permissions-in-sharepoint-2010-t.html)
3. Check if the permission has been changed my someone else, make sure that the permission groups are correct

Comment: Done that, both groups have Read permissions given directly, if I remove those groups, users won't be allowed to enter the site and earleir settings will be gone.

Comment: Have you checked the permissions on each group? Custom permission group?

Comment: Yes, if I remove users frm those Group, they will lose all access

Comment: Not sure about this. But is the page inheriting permissions? My last comment, check the settings on each permission group, maybe someone has modified the standard permissions.

Comment: Is the user part of Site Collection Admin ?

Comment: No, users are not the part of CA